# Any workarounds for protobyname error?

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell

When I try to apply IP Tables to a rooted android device via ADB I get the following error:

```
protoent* getprotobyname(char const*)(3) is not implemented on android
```

I have done some research over the internet and understand this is an outstanding error. I have not seen any workarounds or fixes if there is any? (or at least none that were written in plain English).

If anyone could explain or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

this post was helpful ...at least it solved this error

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mozilla.dev.b2g/6vgCZn0s0Xw/lGiaGrS0YJIJ

and number codes to replace names:

> http://www.diablotin.com/librairie/networking/tcpip/ch02_07.htm